# JSONObject is getting null response

Tags: android, json

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
               Config.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {



                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("id","");
                        editor.putString("email", email);
                        editor.putString("user_name", userName);
                        editor.putString("user_pass", userPass);
                        editor.putString("confirm_pass", confirmPassword);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
```

logcat:

**Register Response: null**

> org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: share the url and response.

Comment: post your json please

Comment: I think it's because your response is `null` & you need to handle it before parsing the JSON. So you can handle it with put this code `if(response!=null) before your try{} code` if still not working try put `if(!response.equals("null"))`

Comment: what is the output of this `Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());` ?

Answer (score 0):

this is url : http://pkmnd.in/rahul/register.php
i am getting expected response in browser.. 
{"result":"fail","message":"Please enter a valid email"}

Comment: Your json Response is not valid....

here2005{"result":"fail","message":"Please enter a valid email"}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Response is not valid...tell the backend to remove the text front from json response. Below is your JSON Response>>

```
here2005{"result":"fail","message":"Please enter a valid email"}
```

Comment: that text is from mysqli_connect_errno() i am checking some conditions.

Comment: 2005 means: problem in host... i corrected that .. now i am getting 1045 means: access denied

Comment: need help on this.

Comment: Tell your backend team to correct it!! What is your new json you are getting...can you show me....in postman show the text format not json format...!!